# Do your PhD fast or strong?

Tags: phd, postdocs

I am in the middle of my PhD and have some strategic decisions to make. I have the opportunity to finish my PhD more rapid, although it would compromise some perspectives/research, it will still (probably) be accepted.

Alternatively, I can use my last year of PhD to research more to deliver a better overall PhD package, but then I would have to delay postdoc (and better pay).

My supervisor's concern is that my PhD delivery is important for future references, so it would be in my(ours) benefit to make it as strong as possible.

Is his suggestion valid? Would a stronger PhD delivery potentially be better on a "CV" than one year of postdoctoral research?

Comment: Do you already have a position for a postdoc, or are you just assuming that you will get one after you finish? Are you planning to stay in academia, or do you want to go in a different direction after some time as postdoc?

Comment: I have it confirmed unofficially. My plan is currently to continue with academia, but please feel free to share your reflections for a different direction also (e.g industry).

Comment: For the academic work, a good/strong PhD should be better. Some people pursue a PhD only for the letters in front of their name, in this case, they might prefer to finish sooner rather than later, irrespective of competence. - Also: Will the extra time improve your understanding of the topic? Taking longer is then possibly advised, especially if you want to stay in academia.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do post PhD. Finish stronger if you wanted to pursue your career as a researcher post PhD

Answer (score 1):

I think the quality of your research depends a lot on the quality of your environment. If you publish a few good papers, you have a higher chance to find a postdoc in a strong group and publish even more good papers, which will improve the chance to find a faculty position. No one will ask how long your PhD took. If you get lucky with your first postdoc, in the sense that you keep publishing high quality work with them, you may not have to do a second, or you would get a very strong second position and then obtain a faculty position.

On the other hand, if your intention is to eventually find a job in industry, or you already have some great opportunity, finishing early is a good idea. The extra-year would only give you more time to do a proper job search in this case.